# which is the right way of declaring an array to be used within the loop

Tags: php

Which would be the right way of declaring an array inside a loop with regard to below example.

method 1:

```
$string = array();
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
  $string[] = $i;
}
```

method 2:

```
$string = array();
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
  $string = $i;
}
```

method 3:

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
  $string[] = $i;
}
```

Comment: The optimum way to accomplish *this specific* example would be `$string = range(0,4);`.

Comment: 2nd would overwrite $string wit an int so after the for you have an int in your $string and something like foreach($string as $str){} would give you a warning

Comment: wow mario, that is awesome, never knew about that function, although the above example is just an example not the actual code, i appreciate on sharing your thought on this, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is the best method .

second one just override the value and last value will be stored

and the third one is not declaring array that cause the php performance to be low. in this case php first create the array and then assign the value which is not a optimized way and take more time to executed php and at the last it take much time to execute your php script.

so first one is the best

Comment: you mean to say if i have to use an array either i need to declare it everytime or automatically it is counted as variable isn't it?

Comment: @Ibrahim: Yes, Definitely. That is PHP, Variables can be initialized dynamically but You should declare them before using that optimize your code and will be executed fast

Comment: oh ok, there is no way to declare variable datatype in a SOP isn't it(Leave OOPS aside)? by declaring the variable do you mean to say it is better i assign the value to a variable at the start of code? does this improve anything?

Comment: @ibrahim: You can not think how this line of code can improve performance `$string = array();`. Mean you are telling PHP that you are going to use `$string` as an array and then PHP will not use the algorithm to determine the type of variable. Hope you get this

Comment: @Shakti, sorry but nope: the performance won't be improved in any way. `$string = array()` looks for $string in memory, see there is not, creates an array; then `$string[] = blabla` puts some data in it. Instead, simply `$string[] =` will look for the $string array in memory; see there's none; create it. Once it's created, in every subsequent loop everything will work exactly like in the first example.

Comment: @cbrandolino: Read some article on PHP code optimization you will understand what I wanted to say here. One of them http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=13769

Comment: @Shakti, I understand. It just isn't true.

Comment: @cbrandolino: You did not understand actually. Why we argue. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

option a would be the best:

```
$string = array();
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
  $string[] = $i;
}
```

this is because just in case u want to use `$string` later and you did not do **anything** in the loop, it still exists and you wont hit an error

Answer (score 2):

1 and 3 will work, while 2 will overwrite the value of `string` every time.

1 is clearer but, if that's all there is in the loop, quite unnecessarily verbose.

Also, that variable name made me wonder: you don't plan to make a string out of that array, do you? In case, there's a better way.

---

I see you needed a string. In that case, what you should do is

```
 $string = '';
 for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
    $string .= $i;
 }
```

`.=` is a concatenation operator; appends right-side argument to left-side argument.

Comment: yes i wish to make a string out of it, the above code just illustrate the example and not the actual code,  as i was getting confused on which is the correct way of declaring and using an array i posted this question, if you have anything more to suggest i will appreciate your thought :)